# Google Sheets API Response IList object to String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, api

```
static string StringEntryRequest()
    {
        var range = "NET!A1";
        var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
            Console.WriteLine("Execute");
        ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Execute complete");
        IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            string i = values.ToString();
        return (i);
    }
```

I have created a Application in C# which should return the Value of a Cell in a Spreedsheet. The Problem is that i can't convett the IList Object into a String. My Current code works fine but just the conversion from IList to String seems impossible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to convert the given IList into a String with the following Method:

```
        foreach (var value in values)
        {  
            string i = value[0].ToString();
            return i;
        }
```

But as Joel points out in a comment,

```
return values[0][0].ToString();
```

is easier and less code.

Comment: Why a `foreach` if you're going to `return` in the first iteration? You could just as easily replace **all** of that code with `return values[0][0].ToString();`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yea you are right. I wasn't thinking about that tbh. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welecom to SO, did your try that ?

```
    Private Function ConvertToListOfString(lstObject As IList(Of Object)) As List(Of String)
    Return lstObject.Select(Function(e) e.ToString()).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, im not sure which language that is but it is definitely not C#. If it is and im just not informed correctly well then i can tell you that it does not work. But Thanks.
Ive done research and it is Visual Basic.